# Matter.js prevent mouse drag while still being able to collide with other objects

Tags: javascript, matter.js

While creating my own version of the [Matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) [slingshot demo](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot)<sup>[[source](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/slingshot.js)]</sup> I got stuck while trying to prevent the projectile from being draggable after it was shot.

#### TL;DR

Looking for some guidance to stop the projectile from being draggable *after* it was fired.

#### My attempt:

Create 3 [collisionFilter](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter) categories;

1. **0x0001**: `static`: Ground, platform, etc
2. **0x0002**: `drag`: Items that interact with mouse
3. **0x0004**: `nodrag`: Items that **cannot** interact with the mouse, **but does collide with everything else**

This works great, everything collides with each other, and I'm only able to drag the projectile (`drag`), not the targets (`nodrag`).

So my next challenge was to toggle the projectile from `drag` to `nodrag` after it was fired. Otherwise, you can grep the projectile and use it like a *Wrecking Ball*.

So Just before I add a new projectile to the elastic, I've tried toggling the `collisionFilter` to `nodrag` using the following code:

```js
Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {

    // If Rock is outside drag-range
    if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 && (rock.position.x > dragborder_x || rock.position.y < dragborder_y)) {

        rock.collisionFilter = { category: cat.nodrag };
        ...
```

#### Problem^^

Unfortunately this prevents the projectile from colliding with everything, even the walls (`static`). Even the targets with `nodrag` collide with the walls. So I have no clue why the projectile stops colliding after switching to `nodrag`.

---

Simplified example

- Toggle **line 72** to see the problem as described above

  ```js
  // Failed attempt (line 72)
  // rock.collisionFilter = { category: cat.nodrag };
  ```

```js
// Statics
const vw = window.innerWidth;
const vh = window.innerHeight;
var Engine = Matter.Engine, Render = Matter.Render, Runner = Matter.Runner, Composites = Matter.Composites, Events = Matter.Events, Constraint = Matter.Constraint, MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint, Mouse = Matter.Mouse, World = Matter.World, Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const cat = {
    static:    0x0001,
    nodrag:    0x0002,
    drag:      0x0004
};

// Create world
var engine = Engine.create();
var world = engine.world;

// Create render
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        width: vw,
        height: vh,
        wireframes: false,
        showAngleIndicator: false
    }
});
// render.on()
Render.run(render);

// Create runner
var runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// Body consts
const rock_x = vw * .20;
const rock_y = vh * .66;
const rockOptions = { 
    density: 0.01,
    collisionFilter: {
        category: cat.drag
    }
};
const gift = {
    render: {
        sprite: {}
    },
    collisionFilter: {
        category: cat.nodrag
    }
};

// Add Static bodies
var ground   = Bodies.rectangle(vw * .5, vh * .9, vw * .9, 42, { isStatic: true, render: { fillStyle: '#060a19' } });
var rock     = Bodies.polygon(rock_x, rock_y, 8, 15, rockOptions);
var anchor   = { x: rock_x, y: rock_y };
var elastic  = Constraint.create({ pointA: anchor, bodyB: rock, stiffness: 0.09, render: { lineWidth: 1 } });
var wall     = Composites.stack(vw * .66, 0, 2, (vh * .4) / 15, 1, 0, (x, y) => Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 15, 15, gift));
var platform = Bodies.rectangle(vw * .75, vh * .6, 210, 21, { isStatic: true, render: { fillStyle: '#060a19' }, collisionFilter: { category: cat.static } });
var pyramid  = Composites.pyramid(vw * .30, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, (x, y) => Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 15, 15, gift));

World.add(engine.world, [ ground, pyramid, platform, wall, rock, elastic ]);

// Rock drag
const dragborder_x = rock_x + 20;
const dragborder_y = rock_y - 20;
Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {

    // If Rock is outside drag-range
    if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 && (rock.position.x > dragborder_x || rock.position.y < dragborder_y)) {

        // Failed attempt (line 72)
        // rock.collisionFilter = { category: cat.nodrag };

        // Add new Rock
        rock = Bodies.polygon(rock_x, rock_y, 7, 15, rockOptions);
        World.add(engine.world, rock);

        // Re-bind elastic
        elastic.bodyB = rock;
    }
});

// Mouse control
var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas);
var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    constraint: {
        stiffness: 0.2,
        render: {
            visible: false
        }
    }
});

// Add mouse
World.add(world, mouseConstraint);
render.mouse = mouse;

// Prevent mouse-drag
mouseConstraint.collisionFilter.mask = cat.static | cat.drag;

// Run
Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-js@0.16.1/build/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">
```